# Control AVAudioRecorder from bluetooth commands

Tags: ios, bluetooth, avaudiosession, avaudiorecorder, callkit

I've got this app that allows users to record stuff around. Then when they have Bluetooth accessory (say, headset), they **should** be able to start/stop the recording session by the play/pause button on the Bluetooth device.

I've successfully implemented the starting session using MPRemoteCommandCenter`

```
let rcCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
rcCenter.nextTrackCommand.isEnabled = false
rcCenter.nextTrackCommand.addTarget { _ in return .success }

rcCenter.previousTrackCommand.isEnabled = false
rcCenter.previousTrackCommand.addTarget { _ in return .success }

rcCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand.isEnabled = true
rcCenter.playCommand.isEnabled = true
rcCenter.pauseCommand.isEnabled = true
rcCenter.stopCommand.isEnabled = true

rcCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(remotePlayPauseAction(_:)))
rcCenter.playCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(remotePlayPauseAction(_:)))
rcCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(remotePlayPauseAction(_:)))
rcCenter.stopCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(remotePlayPauseAction(_:)))
```

However, it never runs into my pause/stop action from bluetooth. I wasn't aware of what happened until I saw this in device's console:

> default   18:19:46.609673 +0700   bluetoothd  Received 'get play status' request from device
>
> default   18:19:46.671092 +0700   bluetoothd  Received AVRCP Play command from device
>
> // sending audio session states because app is recording blah blah...
>
> default   18:19:48.246780 +0700   bluetoothd  AudioSendThread starting

This triggered when app not recording -> receive a play command from bluetoothhd -> start recording -> sending session to bluetooth.

And then, I'll press the play/pause button again and get this log:

> default   18:20:09.650855 +0700   bluetoothd  Received call hangup event
>   (AT+CHUP) from device  default   18:20:09.651273
>   +0700 bluetoothd  Found ongoing virtual call - Acking device and notifying upper layers.

=> it looks like the phone is receiving end call signal (note that there's no call in progress, just a recording in session)

So, how do I handler this event? I've tried to used `CallKit` but still no use:

```
let callCenter = CXCallObserver()
callCenter.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)

func callObserver(_ callObserver: CXCallObserver, callChanged call: CXCall) {
   print("Hi!") // not jump in!
}
```

**Update**

I've tried to switch back to old style handler:

```
UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
becomeFirstResponder()
/////////////////
override func remoteControlReceived(with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let event = event, event.type == .remoteControl else { return }
   // Start / pause actions
}
```

And still got the same result (can start but can't stop, getting events `play` and `call hangup` just like before). Now my guess has switched to `AVAudioSession`'s mode and categories but still got no clues.

```
do {
    let session = AVAudioSession.shared()
    // What is the correct params here? 
    // try session.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .voiceChat, options: [.allowBluetoothA2DP, .allowBluetooth])
    // try session.setCategory(.record, options: .allowBluetooth)
    session.setActive(true)
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: Have you figured out a solution? I have the same EXACT problem.

Comment: My guess is that you can only start but can not trigger stop record from remote command control, since they have mode (`audio/recording/call`) conflicting. It seems Android has this issue too.

Comment: Ok, so I found out that, depending on the bluetooth device, we CAN control recording through the bluetooth buttons. I have a special bluetooth device designed for recording which emits AVRCP events, and the AVRCP events pause and resume are correctly being fired on that bluetooth device only. I'm experiencing your behavior with the more mainstream bluetooth devices like the Jaybirds X3 however. Once I find out more info and solution to the devices I'm testing with, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be bluetooth hardware-related. Sorry I can't give you much if any advice here.

I'm doing some ridiculous C++ recording logic that doesn't use AVAudioProducer (I'm using the AudioToolBox Framework) but I'm essentially getting the same issue as you.

All the market devices I've tried (Jabra OTE23, Jaybird X3, Sony WH1000XM2, official Star Trek Communication Badge) exhibit the same behavior where whenever the microphone is on, the bluetooth device will think it's on a virtual call and will only emit call AVRCP events. There doesn't seem to be a way for iOS to listen to these call AVRCP events for some reason.

There is one internal device in my company that (probably accidentally) emits BOTH pause and hangup events whenever the microphone is on and device is in a recording state. As a result, I'm able to pause and resume recording. Do note however this device was specifically designed for recording audio and whatnot. Logs here for proof:

```
default 15:38:53.994336 -0500   bluetoothd  Received call hangup event (AT+CHUP) from device <private>
default 15:38:53.998181 -0500   bluetoothd  Found ongoing virtual call - Acking device and notifying upper layers.
default 15:38:54.001477 -0500   locationd   service mask 0x1 event type 2 event 104 result 0
default 15:38:54.186054 -0500   powerlogHelperd {"msg":"CLCopyAppsUsingLocation", "event":"activity"}
default 15:38:54.473038 -0500   bluetoothd  Received AVRCP Pause command from device <private>
default 15:38:54.475637 -0500   BTAvrcp Request: Command = <Pause>, SenderDevice = <M’s iPhone>, SenderBundleIdentifier = <BTAvrcp>, SenderPID = <419>, commandID = <B46341E9-7B98-4ACE-94A3-D84A8F4A63B1>, remote control interface = <com.apple.AVRCP>, appOptions = <0>, options = <{kMRMediaRemoteOptionSourceID = "00:13:8A:20:1C:70";}> (null) for origin-M’s iPhone-1280262988/client-com.mmodal.SDK.SettingsTest-1015 (SettingsTest)/player-MediaRemote-DefaultPlayer
```

Why is this device acting differently than the other mainstream devices? I don't know yet. I really just wish iOS (and Android) had a way to listen to all raw AVRCP events, but that doesn't seem to be the case right now.

Bluetooth is a crazy tech stack...